# comparing hashes in ruby array to their sibling

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes, and I want to compare each only to it's neighbour.

I thought i was going to use

```
array.combination(2).select{|s1,s2|
   #do my sorting stuff here
}
```

but what I'm getting returned is the comparison of each hash to every other hash. I want to limit that only to it's neighbour (as it is already sorted when it goes into this step).

Any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound like you want `each_cons`

```
array.each_cons(2) do |pair|
   ...
end
```

Will yield the first 2 elements, then the second and third, third and fourth and so on.

Comment: awesome Frederick, thanks. i now see I should always look at #enumerals for these questions which keep popping up.Thanks